# Compositing 1 light through an object?

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency, render-layers, viewlayers

In this scene, I want Ball 1 to be hit by both lights A+B, but light B to pass through Ball 2 (not casting a shadow on Ball 1)

Ball 2, I want to be hit by light A, but not light B

So how do I make ball 2 an alpha for light B only?

I've been trying to render 2 layers with an Alpha Over in the compositor but with no luck so far.

[image]